# to position the canvas over the <img> element

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

i would like to position the canvas provided by html5  over an image element using css.
But I am not able to place the canvas on the image.
Can you please help me out in this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you want the canvas over an image?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <img ...>
    <canvas ...>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position:relative;
}
#container > img,
#container > canvas {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Optionally set the background loading the image with CSS instead:

```
canvas {
    background:url(yourImage.png);
}
```

or draw the image directly into canvas using JS:

```
var img = new Image,
    ctx = documment.getElementById('canvasId').getContext('2d');

img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    /// continue from here...
}
img.src = 'yourImage.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

If both images have the same size, an alternative solution would be to only create a canvas image, but no HTML image. In the Javascript code load the "background" image and render it into the canvas, before rendering your decorations:

[Drawing Images into Canvas Tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/)

This way your DOM stays simpler and you could actually "interact" with the background image pixels.